# Binary Tree to Array: Wrong values inserted into Array

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have no Idea what I'm doing wrong. I have 3 functions to store the data from two binary trees into arrays. My Problem is the following: Everything works fine for arr2 but not for arr1. Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this? Help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The first array looks like it's also containing the values from arr2 and some random numbers.

The first function creates the arrays and calls treeToArray.

```
void merge(Node* n1, Node* n2){
    int l1 = getTreeSize(n1);   
    cout << "array size " << l1 << endl;
    int *arr1 = new int[l1];   
    int i = 0;
    treeToArray(n1, arr1, i);  //This array is not filled how it's supposed to be. 

    int l2 = getTreeSize(n2);
    cout << "array size " << l2 << endl;
    int *arr2 = new int[l2]; //corrected this, thanks!
    int j = 0;
    treeToArray(n2, arr2, j);

    for(int i = 0; i < l1; ++i)
        cout << "array" << arr1[i] << " ";

    merge(arr1, arr2, l1, l2);

}
```

treeToArray is supposed to store the Tree's data into the array.

```
void treeToArray(Node* n, int values[], int index) {
     if(n == NULL)
          return;

     if(n->left != NULL)
          treeToArray(n->left, values, index);

     cout << "speichere " << n->data << endl;
     values[index] = n->data;
     index++;

     if(n->right != NULL)
          treeToArray(n->right, values, index);

 }
```

And getTreeSize returns the size of the Tree.

```
 int getTreeSize(Node* n) {
      if(n == NULL) {
           return 0;
      } else {
           return (getTreeSize(n->left) + getTreeSize(n->right) + 1 ); //
      }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `int *arr2 = new int[3];` in the `merge` function?

Comment: Thanks!! It has to be l2, which is the size of n2. But the problem is not resolved.

Comment: what is `n1` and `n2`?

Comment: n1 and n2 are the root nodes of the trees.

Comment: Sorry. I mean what is the value of `n1` and `n2`? Since you did the same operations of the two parameters, there must be some difference between these two parameters. And in `treeToArray()`, *the `index` of left node will be the same as current node*. That might be the reason.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Can you explain how I can make the `index` unique for both function calls? `n1` contains the numbers 4, 7 an 10 and `n2` contains 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10. I have to create a new binary tree with the numbers that are unique in n2. The new tree should contain 3, 6 an 9.

Comment: As @useless answered, `&` works :).

Comment: Thank you for your help, too! :) Now I can go to sleep soon, it was a very long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your treeToArray function takes an integer index *by value*, which means there is no communication between different calls.

I've annotated the code with the actual values of index in the first call, but you can step through in a debugger to confirm this if you want to follow the recursion.

```
void treeToArray(Node* n, int values[], int index) {
     // start first call with index = 0
     if(n == NULL)
          return;
     if(n->left != NULL)
          treeToArray(n->left, values, index);
     // we passed 0 to the left subtree call, and get nothing back
     // so index is still 0 here

     values[index] = n->data;
     // we just overwrote the left subtree's first element with our data
     index++;

     if(n->right != NULL)
          treeToArray(n->right, values, index);
     // the right subtree now always starts from 1 ...
}
```

If you change it to pass the index *by reference*, the calls can cooperate:

```
void treeToArray(Node* n, int values[], int& index) {
     // start first call with index = 0
     if(n == NULL)
          return;
     if(n->left != NULL)
          treeToArray(n->left, values, index);
     // the left subtree call used a reference to the same
     // index variable, so any modification is visible here too

     values[index] = n->data;
     // we write our node data after the left subtree
     // (using the final value of index from the left subtree call)
     index++;
     // this affects the index in any parent call

     if(n->right != NULL)
          treeToArray(n->right, values, index);
     // the right subtree also advances the same index value
}
```

Note that you could instead *return* the new index, but this is a smaller change to your existing code.

---

For reference, it would be easy to unit-test this function in isolation with some small trees and check the expected output. This would expose the bug before you had introduced a second tree and all the other machinery.

Comment: It works! I am very thankful! I was trying for hours to get this fixed.